# How to retrieve classes of an individual, ignoring classes that are the same, in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I have a taxonomy in my ontology. For some of these classes, there are "sameAs" predicates with other classes.

I need to retrieve the classes of a given individual, which is classified in this taxonomy. However, when two classes are the same (related by "sameAs"), I want to retrieve just one of them.

I am using the following query, for retrieving the labels of the classes:

```
select ?classLabel
where {{
    OPTIONAL {
        URI a ?class
            ?class rdfs:label ?classLabel.
     }
}}
```

It is retrieving the label of the classes of URI. However, it is not excluding the redundante classes (classes that are the same).

How to retrieve just one class of two classes that are the same in SPARQL?

Comment: Use [SAMPLE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggSample).

Comment: Classes do **not** have "sameAs" predicates...if that's the case, you're doing things wrong!

Comment: And it would be good if you "Accept" answers if they are sufficient. This helps in ranking the answers and shows others that have the same or similar questions the most appropriate answer first.